# How to compile ruby in debug mode?

Tags: ruby, internals, mri

There are plenty of ruby debug log calls in the [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/b963fb25d2f683759c273eb21af85c1632122056/thread.c#L1450) that help me better understand internals.

How do you debug ruby vm? Do you have a documentation for that?

I haven't found any information in the GitHub documentation. What I tried but didn't get any result are:

1. Compile ruby in kind of debug mode:

```
./autogen.sh
mkdir build && cd build # it's good practice to build outside of source dir
mkdir ~/.rubies # we will install to .rubies/ruby-master in our home dir
../configure cppflags='-DUSE_RUBY_DEBUG_LOG=1 -DRUBY_DEBUG' --prefix="${HOME}/.rubies/ruby-master"
make install
```

Tried to run ruby with -d flag

```
export RUBY_DEBUG_LOG='/home/root/ruby.log'
export USE_RUBY_DEBUG_LOG=1
export DEBUG=1

bin/ruby -d ~/test.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

I built Ruby today with debugging, and here's what I did.  I experimented with several configure options and flags; this was the minimum I needed for VM logging.

I have a guess about why your build didn't work, which I'll describe at the end.

1. Clone ruby, it's at: `git rev-parse master --short # => 191e4ae33f`
2. Follow the instructions in `doc/contributing/building_ruby.md`.
3. Configure as:

   - Enable the debug CPP macro
   - An install prefix
   - Disable documentation (particular to this build, I didn't need docs)
   - Configure OpenSSL (particular to this build, on macOS)
4. Build, I didn't bother to `make install`

Just to be clear, there were no Ruby or debug-related environment variables influencing the build.

```bash
$ env | egrep -i 'RUBY|DEBUG'
$ git clone https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git
$ cd ruby
$ ./autogen.sh
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ ../configure cppflags="-DUSE_RUBY_DEBUG_LOG=1" --prefix=${HOME}/.rubies/ruby-master --disable-install-doc --with-openssl-dir=$( 
$ make -j8
```

There is no need to pass `-d` or all those environment variables for Ruby to emit the VM debug information, `RUBY_DEBUG_LOG=[dest]` is sufficient.

###### Below is Ruby emitting debug output, and I also verified filtering works.

1. Verify there is no output unless requested, this is expected:

```
$ ./ruby -e ''    # No output, ok
```

2. Ask for debug output on stderr:

```
$ RUBY_DEBUG_LOG=stderr ./ruby -e '' 2>&1 | head -5
RUBY_DEBUG_LOG=stderr [stderr]
   0: rb_ractor_set_current_ec_ ec:0x0000000000000000->0x000000013a704740       vm.c:4046               th:0
   1: heap_add_freepage page:0x000000013b80b000 freelist:0x000000010491ffc8     gc.c:2026               th:0
   2: heap_add_freepage page:0x000000013b80b600 freelist:0x000000010493ffd0     gc.c:2026               th:0
   3: heap_add_freepage page:0x000000013b80bc00 freelist:0x000000010495ffd8     gc.c:2026               th:0
```

3. Ask for specific debug output on stderr:

```
$ RUBY_DEBUG_LOG=stderr RUBY_DEBUG_LOG_FILTER='vm_lock_enter' ./ruby -e '' 2>&1 | head -5
RUBY_DEBUG_LOG=stderr [stderr]
RUBY_DEBUG_LOG_FILTER[0]=vm_lock_enter (all)
   0: vm_lock_enter     start locked:0  gc.c:2799               th:0
   1: vm_lock_enter     rec:1 owner:1   gc.c:2799               th:0
   2: vm_lock_enter     start locked:0  gc.c:2799               th:0
```

You don't mention what revision (or commit) of Ruby you were building.  Since the date of your post, there is this patch on `master`:

```
commit 0d415a322f5dd7158efcbc6c3226266e312620c7
Author: Koichi Sasada <ko1@atdot.net>
Date:   Wed Mar 1 17:07:50 2023 +0900

    Enable DEBUG_LOG feature on USE_RUBY_DEBUG_LOG
    
    `ruby_set_debug_option` is needed for `RUBY_DEBUG_LOG` feature
    so it should be called when `USE_RUBY_DEBUG_LOG` is true.

diff --git a/main.c b/main.c
index 0d0ec147cd..072dc56dd5 100644
--- a/main.c
+++ b/main.c
@@ -23,6 +23,7 @@
 #ifdef HAVE_LOCALE_H
 #include <locale.h>
 #endif
+
 #if defined RUBY_DEVEL && !defined RUBY_DEBUG_ENV
 # define RUBY_DEBUG_ENV 1
 #endif
@@ -46,7 +47,7 @@ int rb_wasm_rt_start(int (main)(int argc, char **argv), int argc, char **argv);
 int
 main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
-#ifdef RUBY_DEBUG_ENV
+#if defined(RUBY_DEBUG_ENV) || USE_RUBY_DEBUG_LOG
     ruby_set_debug_option(getenv("RUBY_DEBUG"));
 #endif
 #ifdef HAVE_LOCALE_H
```

Reading the diff **and** the context lines, and looking at your `./configure`, I think (back in October) you would have needed to pass `--enable-devel` **or** `cppflags="-DRUBY_DEBUG_ENV"`, and not `"-DRUBY_DEBUG"`.  I didn't checkout a commit from that time and to test. :-)

After this patch, if only `USE_RUBY_DEBUG_LOG` is set, then `RUBY_DEBUG` will be enabled in the VM, which is presumably happening in `ruby_set_debug_option()`.

Aside, you may also be interested in the `--enable-devel` option, I did subsequently build with it, but I didn't want to confuse this answer, nor have I investigated details yet.